# MySQL RAND() 7 LIMIT

Tags: sql, random, limit

My database table has 15 records and I want to show 9 at random on screen.

```sql
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9
```

This works as expected, but what if the table only has 9 records? I need to pull 15 random records.

I understand this will duplicate one or more records, but that's my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `select` will only pull the number of records in the table regardless of the `order by`.  You can use various means to duplicate the table data, however, before you order them.  For example, `union all` of the rows together twice:

```
select * from
(
    select * from tablename
    union all
    select * from tablename
) as tmp
order by rand() limit 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunaltly this causes the following error 
"Every derived table must have its own alias" so I suspose i need to lookup alias naming :)

Comment: This of course will show less than 9 results, when the table has 4 or less rows.

Comment: And when the table has 9 or more rows, you may still have duplicates in the (9) results, while other rows are not returned at all. (this may be wanted by the OP but it should be mentioned.

Comment: ypercube added the missing alias.

Answer (score 0):

RAND() itself is not efficient when you deal with a large database.

A better way of doing such query is to:

-1. Query the largest id (assume id is the unique key)

-2. use javascript of php function to generate 15 random numbers from 1 to max_id, push to -array

-3. Implode the array (e.g. $id_list = "'".implode("', '", $id_list)."'")

-4. Select * from tablename where id in ($id_list)

Comment: I do understand the need for optimisation but this is a very small application with never more than 50 records at any one time :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work even if you have only 1 row in the table. If you have less than 15 (say 11) rows, you'll have all 11 in the result plus 4 more random ones:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., colN                -- the columns of `tablename` only
FROM
  ( SELECT a.i, b.j, t.*
    FROM
            ( SELECT *, RAND() AS rnd 
              FROM tablename 
              ORDER BY rnd LIMIT 15
            ) AS t 
        CROSS JOIN
            ( SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
              SELECT 3      UNION ALL SELECT 4 )
            AS a
        CROSS JOIN
            ( SELECT 1 AS j UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
              SELECT 3      UNION ALL SELECT 4 )
            AS b
    ORDER BY i, j, rnd
        LIMIT 15
  ) AS t15
ORDER BY RAND() ;
```

If you want "more" randomness, having duplicate or triplicate rows in the results with possibly some rows not shown at all, replace the last five lines with:

```
            AS b
    ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 15
  ) AS t15 ;
```